# How can I change an image when I click on another image? (Without onclick)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I´m doing a landing page and wanted to make the main image change when I click on other images. I´ve tried with this

```html
<div class="thumb">
  <ul>
    <li> 
      <img id="img1" class="smallImg coupe" src="./assets/smallCar1.png" alt="small img">
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <img id="img2" class="smallImg" src="./assets/smallCar2.png" alt="small img">
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <img id="img3" class="smallImg" src="./assets/smallCar3.png" alt="small img">
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

```js
function imageChange() {
  let picDefault = document.getElementById("img");

  if ((picDefault = "img")) {
    picDefault.src = "./assets/img1.png";
  }
}
picDefault.addEventListener(click, imageChange);
```

Comment: `click` needs to be in quotes in `addEventListener()`

Comment: `picDefault()` is local to the function, you can't use it outside

Comment: `if ((picDefault = "img"))` will never be true. `picDefault` is a DOM element, not a string. What are you trying to do there?

Comment: Hey @Barmar, `if ((picDefault = "img"))` will _always_ be true as it is an assignment with a "truesy" result :D ...

Comment: Anyway, what's the question here?

Comment: Yes, I agree - :D - ... the question needs more focus.

Answer (score 1):

Sample code for updating an image by clicking on another image. Use case might be completely different.

```js
const thumps =  document.getElementsByClassName("thump"); // secondary images
const main =  document.getElementById("main");

for(let i = 0; i < thumps.length; i ++) {
  const el = thumps[i]
  el.addEventListener("click", function(e) { //  add click handler
    const elem = e.target;
    main.src = elem.src;
  })
}
```

```css
#main {
  max-width: 300px;
}

.thump {
  width: 100px;
  margin: 4px;
  padding: 2px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h5>Main Image</h5>
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1644243019151-0bb97ce1af84" id="main"/>
</div>

<h5>Click Images below thumpnails to update main image</h5>
<div class="row">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1644235279538-4cc7cbdca6a8" class="thump">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1643443026948-c17b9bb16758" class="thump">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1644243019151-0bb97ce1af84" class="thump">
</div>
```